# How to import file excel 2007 into phpmyadmin using php?

Tags: php, excel, import, phpmyadmin

How to import file excel 2007 into phpmyadmin using php?
I have a large file excel in .xlsx format (40MB) and i want to import this file to phpmyadmin.

Comment: See http://webimpulse.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/hello-world/.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. But how to apply it using php code?

Comment: For that you must use some library, as you can see in http://major.io/2008/11/07/importing-excel-files-into-mysql-with-php/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066961/import-data-from-excel-in-php.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['form_submit']))
 {
    include("db.php"); 
    require_once 'Classes/excel_reader.php';

    $file1 = $_FILES['excelfile']['tmp_name'];
    $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($file1);
    $sheet = $data->sheets[0];
    $rows = $sheet['cells'];
    $rowCount = count($rows);


    for($i=2;$i<=$rowCount;$i++)
    {
        $name = $data->val($i,1);
        $email = $data->val($i,2);
        $password = $data->val($i,3);

        $sql = "insert into $tabel_name (`name`,`email`,`password`) values ('$name','$email','$password')";
mysql_query($sql);
    }

 }
 ?>
 <html>
      <head>
          <title>How To Import Excel (.xls) File To MySql Database Using PHP</title>
      </head>
      <body>
      <center><h1>zero-error-script.blogspot.in</h1></center>
      <form name="import_export_form" method="post" action="import.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label>Select Excel File : </label><input type="file" name="excelfile"/><br>
      <input type="submit" name="form_submit"/>
      </form>
      </body>
 </html>
```

[Download full example with source code](http://zero-error-script.blogspot.in/2014/06/how-to-import-export-excel-xls-to-excel.html)

Comment: I can't apply this for format .xlsx with 700.000 row. I have tried this anytime, and it's not work.

Comment: it's depend on your server, because its process time is huge.